# What does SEO score reported by whois.domaintools.com mean and what factors influence it?

Tags: seo, whois

I created a website and purchased the second-level domain. I didn't put any content yet and I can't even find it by googling the domain name; despite thas [whois.domaintools.com](https://whois.domaintools.com/) reports that my SEO score is 69% (better than other quite popular websites I know).

I wonder what it does mean and how it virtually affects ranking. Will the score grow or decrease accordingly to site performance? What are the criteria adopted in assigning this "SEO score" to a new website and how does it evolve later?

Comment: If there is anyone who can give you an accurate SEO score this is Google Analystics, Webmaster tools (Search console) and, google mobile friendly, and other google stuff, but whois information gives inaccurate information about your SEO score because it is based on unreal information in my opinion, I haven't met a crawler of whois web services, there might be but I haven't met any and without a crawler he cannot give a score of your content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me see. No site. Not found in a search engine. Yet score is 69%. Huh. Something does not add up.

That is because these sites are junk. Do not pay attention to this non-sense. Not from any site.

In the example you cited, they are just attempting to score the on-page optimization of the home page. Since you do not have one, this score would be misleading. I assume that there is something that can be seen. However, do not take your SEO advice from a machine. That would be foolish. There are some helpful tools, however, none of them can fully lead you to success, only help guide you to making decisions. Not advice. Not solutions. Information. Some actionable. Some not. After time you will learn what is worth looking at. Again, the secret is that most all of the online web site performance sites are junk or at least half-junk. The trick is to know what is real and what is not real.

There are other forms of online web performance sites. In fact, there are a ton of them. Here is a fact for you. It is absolutely impossible to measure the performance of a website externally. There are only a handful of sites that can tell you anything of value and two of them are the webmaster tools offered by Google and Bing.

Comment: Totally Agree, some of sites using outdated/bogus things to calculate seo score, Funny things happen, when we analysis their site first :D